# PHP MySQL counting provided value in 5 columns

Tags: mysql

```
+------+------+------+------+------+
| num1 | num2 | num3 | num4 | num5 |
+------+------+------+------+------+
|    5 |    8 |   18 |   38 |   45 |
|   12 |   43 |   44 |   46 |   50 |
|    8 |   18 |   45 |   46 |   50 |
+------+------+------+------+------+
```

My database looks like this, and I want to have a while loop, which counts how many time(s) there is one number in all of these columns. E.g. in this case it would be like that:

```
5 - 1
8 - 2
18 - 1
38 - 1
```

I have tried with GROUP BY but results wasn't as they should be.

Comment: With a loop in your script you could easily do this, by just selecting all the data (no GROUPing), and then adding up the number of occurrences for each number in an array, using the numbers as array keys … if there is no entry in the array yet for a number, then you create the element with the value 1, otherwise you just add 1 onto the current count.

Comment: This is not a database. In fact, in a pure RDBMS sense, it's not even a table. See normalization. And your result set doesn't correspond to your data set.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
select num1 as number from table 
union all 
select num2 from table 
union all 
select num3 from table 
union all 
select num4 from table 
union all 
select num5 from table
```

to get a list of all used numbers

We now use this for grouping:

```
select number, count(*) 
from (select num1 as number from table union all select num2 from table union all select num3 from table union all select num4 from table union all select num5 from table) t1 
group by number
```

Comment: Hi @powerthepower if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.